# SISS throwing error "invalid character value for cast specification" when running in job

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

When I run my code in sql it runs just fine. However when running in the ssis using ODBC job giving me below error.

[OLE DB Staging Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid character value for cast specification".

[ODBC Source [29]] Error: Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) error occurred. state: '22018'. Native Error Code: 0. [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification

[ODBC Source [29]] Error: Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) error occurred. state: '01004'. Native Error Code: 0. [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]String data, right truncation

[ODBC Source [29]] Error: Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) error occurred. state: '01S07'. Native Error Code: 0. [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Fractional truncation

```
CONVERT(varchar(10), a.PurcDate, 20) AS 'PurcDate'
```

I am trying to convert this to nvarchar in my source table. When I take this line above out my query it works just fine. My other converts look like above work just fine for the other datetime columns. This is the only one which is not working. There are no null values or blank values for this column which I already checked. When I move this code somewhere else it processes only 2000 records. I feel like it is a formatting issue.

Answer (score 0):

The following looks to be the error: `String data, right truncation`

It is likely that source data length is greater than 10 characters. If you run a select query using `MAX(LEN(PurcDate))`, you may find the largest value. You can check whether this column is really a `Date` field or possibly a `DateTime` field or a `VARCHAR` field.

Based on the length of the field and the required data type, you can do  appropriate conversion.